# Debugging PHP Form Handling, with Dynamic HTML Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, debugging

I'm using this *HTML* code to allow the user to add more fields and remove them from this order form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form Processing with PHP | Tech Stream</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 if(rowCount < 20){       // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
   var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
   newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
  }
 }else{
   alert("Maximum Photos per order is 20.");
      
 }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
 var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
  var row = table.rows[i];
  var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
  if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
   if(rowCount <= 1) {       // limit the user from removing all the fields
    alert("Cannot Remove all Picture fields.");
    break;
   }
   table.deleteRow(i);
   rowCount--;
   i--;
  }
 }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
 <form action="process.php" class="register" method="POST">
  <fieldset class="row1">
    <legend>Order Details</legend>
    <p> 
     <input type="button" value="Add Picture" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
     <input type="button" value="Remove Picture" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
     <p>(All acions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
    </p>
               <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1"> <!-- These Fields get duplicated -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <p>
      <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="" /></td>
       <td>
       <label for="BX_file">Filename</label>
       <input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="BX_file[]">
          </td>
       <td>
       <label for="BX_gallery">Gallery</label>
       <select id="BX_gallery" name="BX_gallery" required="required">
        <option>....</option>
        <option>Nature</option>
        <option>Stilllife</option>
        <option>Portrait</option>
        <option>Constructed</option>
        <option>Nature</option>
        <option>Black & White </option>
        <option>Rotarian Dinner Dance 25/04/2015</option>
       </select>
       </td>
       <td>
       <label for="BX_medium">Medium</label>
       <select id="BX_medium" name="BX_medium" required="required">
        <option>....</option>
        <option>Small Print</option>
        <option>Medium Print</option>
        <option>Large Print</option>
        <option>Custom Print</option>
        <option>CD Image Disc</option>
        <option>Digital Download</option>
       </select>
       </td>
       <td>
       <label for="BX_quantity">Quantity</label>
       <input type="number" required="required" class="small"  name="BX_quantity[]">
          </td>
       </p>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table> <!-- End of Fields that are duplicated. -->
    <fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Terms and Mailing</legend>
                <p class="agreement">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                    <label>*  I accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                </p>    
    <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="row3">
                <legend>Other</legend>
                <p class="notes">
                    <input type="text">
                    <label>Additional Notes</label>
                </p>    
    <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
   <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirm &raquo;" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
        </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm now trying to handle the field inputs via *PHP* so they can be sent via email to me. However I can't seem to get it working. Could anyone point out where my *PHP* code is going wrong?

```
<?php 
$str_File = $_POST['BX_FILE'];
$str_Gall = $_POST['BX_GALLERY'];
$str_Med = $_POST['BX_MEDIUM'];
$int_Quant = $_POST['BX_QUANT'];
$str_Notes = $_POST['NOTES'];
//Gets all the values and saves them to the variables in  array format.

$int_Num = count($FILE) //Gets the size of th array.

for ($x = 1; $x <= $int_Num; $x++) {
$str_ORD = "Order Field: $x, Filename: $str_File[$x], Gallery: $str_Gall[$x], Photo Medium: $str_Med[$x], Quantity: $int_Quant[$x]"
} 
//Loops through all the arrays assembling the message for the email.

mail("harrysanderson@live.co.uk","Order Test",$str_ORD)
//Sends email.
```

[This](http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Dynamic-Form-Processing-with-PHP) is the tutorial I've been following:

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Sorry I'm a beginner when it comes to *PHP*.

Comment: What does "can't seem to get it working" mean?  How does it fail?

Comment: If by `$FILE` you mean the **superglobal variable**, it's `$_FILES`

Comment: It fails by not sending an email instead the page changes so that you can see the PHP code. And sorry the $str_File is only intended to hold the values from the HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

Key values in post array are case sensitive. Use the same names in POST which you have used in your input elements.

For example,
`<input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="BX_file[]">`

Here, POST should be `$_POST['BX_file']`

Comment: I've tried correcting the names so that they match up correctly but I'm still having no luck?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

1. Your field names are the same. BX_file[] won't turn into an array (if that's what's intended) just because you put brackets at the end of it. You need to manage input names dynamically via JS, or else your fields will mutually overwrite each other at POST event.

See the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="test5.php">
            <input type="text" name="input_foo">
            <input type="text" name="input_bar">
            <input type="text" name="input_foo">
            <input type="submit" value="post">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actioin file:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [input_foo] => test3 [input_bar] => test2 )
```